# iOS - parse a string using whitespace

Tags: ios, parsing, nsstring, string-parsing

I am an iOS newbie, so please pardon me if this is a beginner level question.

I have a string "hu_HU  Hungary:Hungarian" and I want to put it into an array like {"hu", "HU", "Hungary:Hungarian"}. How would I parse it to remove the whitespace and then the underscore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet%3a) method of NSString

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired effect you must change the '_' to a ' ' or vice versa. Then you can use componentsSeparatedByString, like so:

```
NSString *source = @"hu_HU Hungary:Hungarian";
source = [source stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@" "];
NSArray *components = [source componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
NSLog(@"%@",components);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *theStr = @"hu_HU Hungary:Hungarian";
NSArray  *pieces = [theStr componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: @"_ "]];
//pieces = {"hu", "HU", "Hungary:Hungarian"}

pieces = [theStr componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [[NSCharacterSet  alphanumericCharacterSet] invertedSet]];
//pieces = {"hu", "HU", "Hungary", "Hungarian"}
//the motivation for this is a better defined set of non-alphanumeric characters
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
NSString *myString = @"hu_HU Hungary:Hungarian";
myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"_" withString:@" "];
NSArray *myArray = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

Answer (score 0):

All of these answers share an annoying problem.  They assume that the items are separated by one and only one space.

```
NSString *theStr = @"hu_HU Hungary:Hungarian";
NSArray  *pieces = [theStr componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: @"_ "]];
//pieces = {"hu", "HU", "Hungary:Hungarian"}

NSString *theStr = @"hu_HU  Hungary:Hungarian"; // note extra space
NSArray  *pieces = [theStr componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: @"_ "]];
//pieces = {"hu", "HU", " ", "Hungary:Hungarian"}
```